# protractor appears to interrupt Node when run against Firefox

Tags: node.js, angular, firefox, protractor

Background: I am running tests in the Protractor framework against a website written in Angular using Firefox as the browser

The website initially loads with a Server-side render. The follow-up client-side render appears to get interrupted. Angular is available, but nothing in the Dom loads.

Asking Google hasn't helped(none of the Stackoverflow results appeared to be relevant). Didn't see any open issues or closed issues on the Protractor github which appeared to be relevant

I'm not sure what's relevant to the investigation, so starting information:

- Firefox version: 65
- geckodriver version: v0.24.0 [last]
- protractor version: 5.4.1
- framework: jasmine
- directconnect = true

Has anyone resolved this issue before? Is there additional information which would be relevant. What have I missed? The same tests running against Chrome pass without issue

Comment: Can you share the failure message you receive?

Comment: The tests fail with element not found errors. There are no relevant console or network errors